# decode json file with php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode a json file with php, but it's not displaying anything. The code I have so far:

PHP

```
$str = file_get_contents('llt_stops.json');
$json = json_decode($str, true);
print_r($json, true);
```

JSON

```
{
  "stops": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Andreaskyrkan",
      "locId": "740037195"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Ankarkronan",
      "locId": "740037329"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Arcushallen",
      "locId": "740037262"
    }
]
}
```

I've also tried with a foreach loop, but it doesn't display anything either.

```
foreach ($json['stops'] as $field => $value) {
// Use $field and $value here
}
```

Update:
I get this error, don't know whats wrong with the loop:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/E9csmHVM maybe it's the swedish characters å ä ö that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. It was the swedish characters in the json file that were not correctly displayed. I changed them from ? to å ä ö, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print_r($json);
```

With true it returns the value, does not print it.